# Hive table re-create before load every date

Tags: hive, loading, external-tables, hiveddl

I saw application are droping external table and creating again then loading the data and runnning msck command every time data load..what is the benefit of this on every time dropping and creating?

Answer (score 1):

There is no benefit in dropping and recreating `EXTERNAL` table, because dropping table leaves data intact.

Though there may be a benefit in dropping and re-creating `MANAGED` table because it will drop data as well.